# How Do I Add email to this script

Tags: linux, scripting, sftp, expect

I need to find out how to add an email notice if files were transferred successfully "Transfer Was Successful" or if their was a problem "There was a Problem".......what am I doing wrong...this is the message I get after files are transfered

```
sftp> invalid command name "EOD"  
while executing               
"EOD"                             

#!/usr/bin/expect<<EOD > output.log      
#
spawn sftp -o Port=22 HOSTDNS@HOSTDNS.com    
expect "assword:"                        
send "password\r"                         
expect "sftp>"                           
send "lcd /usr/lib/basic/TEMP/TRANS\r"   
expect "sftp>"                           
send "cd /home/denni/STORAGE\r"          
expect "sftp>"                           
send "mput *\r"                          
expect "sftp>"                           
send "bye\r"                             
EOD                                                                             
RC=$?                                                                           
if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then                                                      
  cat output.log | mail -s "Errors Received"
"username@somewhere.com"  
else                                                                            
  echo "Success" | mail -s "Transfer Successful"
"username@somewhere.com "                                                                             
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is not specific to the email sending. It points to a problem with adding a '<<END_MARKER' construct into a shell script pseudo-comment. Actually it's very interesting, to my opinion. But it needs major edits. Please analyze the essence of a problem and prepare a _minimal_ example each time you post a Q.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got bash at the top of the script, and that there aren't any spaces after the EOD. This works for me. Note that I removed the #! from the beginning of the expect binary as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/expect <<EOD > output.log
spawn sftp username@hostname
expect "assword:"
send "password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "ls\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\r"
EOD
```